# Earliest and Lastdate for each year in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a column with 3 columns. I have multiple records for a year. As you see  some of my records as follows

```
 ID stardate  enddate
 1 1/1/2010   5/3/2010
 2 2/4/2010   NULL -**EDIT**
 3 1/2/2011   5/6/2011
 4 3/4/2011   NULL -**EDIT**
```

I want to get a result for the earliest date in that year and the last date in that year. So output could be like

```
 **EDITED:**     1/1/2010   12/31/2010 - For Year 2010
 **EDITED:**     1/2/2011   12/31/2011 - For Year 2011
```

How can i get that in a query?If you need more info,please ask. Thanks

**EDIT:** If for the year if one of the columns read NULL then I have to consider the last day of the year as the enddate. i.e.12/31/YYYY. And I need to do that for each year again.

Comment: What database are you using?  Are the dates stored as date/datetime or as strings?

Comment: @GordonLinoff.Using SQL. storing as datetime datatype.

Comment: **SQL** is just the **query language** - used by many databases. It's not a concrete database product as such. Please update your tags with the **actual, concrete database system** (and its version!) that you're using - is it Oracle? MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? SQL Server? Something else entirely???

Comment: So your main issue appears to be the added condition, because the original question was indeed rather trivial. But since you had already received answers to the original question by the time you realised your problem was more complex, I'd suggest you roll back your present question and post a new one where you specifically ask about the main issue (which is, I believe, how to default a NULL date in one column to the last day of another date column's year).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use `DATE` (or related) columns in a MySQL table, something like this should serve your request:

```
SELECT   MIN(startdate), 
         MAX(enddate), 
         YEAR(startdate) 
FROM     my_table 
GROUP BY YEAR(startdate);
```

This groups all entries by year (of the startdate) and show you the minimum and maximum entries for each year as you want. See also the documentation for the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function in MySQL.

There are similar date functions and possibilities if you are using an other database system. Usually you can easily find them by googling the database system and something like "date functions".

Comment: Thanks. It got me started. I realize I actually need a variation of that question. SHould have posted the correct one earlier, but requirement changed. SO can you take a look at the EDITED question.?

Answer (score 1):

```
select MIN(stardate),max(enddate)
from [Tablename]
where YEAR(enddate)=2013
```